# DescribeSObjectResult cannot find field

Tags: apex, schema

Let's say we have a simple code

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult res = Schema.SObjectType.Account;
system.debug(Schema.SObjectType.Account.fields.Name.isAccessible());
system.debug(res.fields.Name.isAccessible());
system.debug(res.isAccessible());
```

but it fails in line 3 with the message
`Line: 3, Column: 25 Variable does not exist: Name`
what did i miss?

Comment: Looks like it works only on Line 2 manner `In the example above, the system uses special parsing to validate that the final member variable (Name) is valid for the specified sObject at compile time. When the parser finds the fields member variable, it looks backwards to find the name of the sObject (Account). It validates that the field name following the fields member variable is legitimate. The fields member variable only works when used in this manner.`

Answer (score 4):

`fields` has a `Map` return type, because your `fields` is `SObjectTypeFields` when you use `Schema.DescribeSObjectResult`.

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult res = Schema.SObjectType.Account;
System.debug(Schema.SObjectType.Account.fields.Name.isAccessible());
System.debug(res.fields.getMap().get('Name').getDescribe().isAccessible());
System.debug(res.isAccessible());
```